# How to solve "Error while requesting server, " while running a simple mail request using docusign

Tags: docusignapi

> getting error Exception: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error
>   while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 401 with
>   response Body: '{   "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
>   "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled.
>   An Integrator key was not specified." }'

while using running the following sample code, no idea about how to solve this. Can any one help me solving this error

```
public class DocuSignExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] fileBytes = null;

        String pathToDocument = "/TestFile.pdf";

        try
        {
            String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

            // read file from a local directory
            Path path = Paths.get(currentDir + pathToDocument);
            fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        }
        catch (IOException ioExcp)
        {
            // TODO: handle error
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ioExcp);
            return;
        }

        // create an envelope that will store the document(s), field(s), and recipient(s)
        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envDef.setEmailSubject("Please sign this document sent from Java SDK)");

        // add a document to the envelope
        Document doc = new Document();  
        String base64Doc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileBytes);
        doc.setDocumentBase64(base64Doc);
        doc.setName("TestFile"); // can be different from actual file name
        doc.setFileExtension(".pdf"); // update if different extension!
        doc.setDocumentId("1");

        List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();
        docs.add(doc);
        envDef.setDocuments(docs);

        // add a recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email we used above
        Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.setEmail("dijo@gmail.com");
        signer.setName("dijo francis");
        signer.setRecipientId("1");


        // create a |signHere| tab somewhere on the document for the signer to sign
        // here we arbitrarily place it 100 pixels right, 150 pixels down from top
        // left corner of first page of first envelope document
        SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.setDocumentId("1");
        signHere.setPageNumber("1");
        signHere.setRecipientId("1");
        signHere.setXPosition("100");
        signHere.setYPosition("150");

        // can have multiple tabs, so need to add to envelope as a single element list
        List<SignHere> signHereTabs = new ArrayList<SignHere>();      
        signHereTabs.add(signHere);
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
        tabs.setSignHereTabs(signHereTabs);
        signer.setTabs(tabs);

        // add recipients (in this case a single signer) to the envelope
        envDef.setRecipients(new Recipients());
        envDef.getRecipients().setSigners(new ArrayList<Signer>());
        envDef.getRecipients().getSigners().add(signer);

        // send the envelope by setting |status| to "sent". To save as a draft set to "created" instead
        envDef.setStatus("sent");

        try
        {
            // instantiate a new EnvelopesApi object
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            // call the createEnvelope() API
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope("46e16c10-69f0-4258-b1ff-1ab5c61f2619", envDef);
            System.out.println("Envelope has been sent to " + signer.getEmail());
            System.out.println("EnvelopeSummary: " + envelopeSummary);
        }
        catch (com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The message has the problem. Check that your API Key is still valid and is correctly set.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thanks **JM**, now I'm getting error `Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: Missing code for grant_type=authorization_code`? can u help me to solve this error?

Comment: I'm not sure about the SDK you are using, but when using the REST API, there are ways you have to prepare your request. See this [link](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant).

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with the Integration Key. I would recommend to look at this recent video that talks about integration keys and how to configure them - https://youtu.be/3dTXo5oSmjk